# Checking in Android if web server have Google refresh token

Tags: android, web, oauth-2.0

I've implemented Android to web server Google authentication as described here:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth

It works fine, but I'm having trouble implementing one of their guidelines:

"The first request of a session also includes a query to the back-end as to whether it has the appropriate level of online access to the scopes it needs to work on the user’s behalf."

I did that by storing a persistent cookie so the web server have the user identity, and can check that it have a refresh token. However, if the user sign out or reinstall the app (happens a lot during development), the server no longer have any means to identify the user and check if it have a refresh token. In this case, the Android app must get a new token. This is very problematic because Google have limitation on how many refresh tokens can be issued.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't figure out what. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the Oauth access tokens persistently which is not depending on the user signed out.

Comment: I already store the token on the server. My question is different. Suppose I have a device with 2 Google accounts. I install the app, login and select 1 of the 2 accounts. I logout, and then login again. How can I tell weather the user already login before?

Comment: each account will have a separate OAuth token, map each to the user the first time you retrieve it.